# Android: Change tapped textview's color to green and others to black

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text1"/>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text2"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

How can i write code such that when the listview item's text1 is clicked, the selected text1 of that particular item is turned to textcolor green.......and all the other items reset to text color black.

So far i have this code in my custom in my getView() of the custom adapter

```
 TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtDateUploaded);

 text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean settogreen = (boolean) v.getTag();
        if (settogreen) {
            ((TextView)v).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        } else {
            ((TextView)v).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }
        v.setTag(!settogreen);
    }
});
```

And the problem is this only toggles between green and black of individual text1's regardless of the state of other list item's text1 and does not reset others back to black

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RadioGroup` to achieve this:

put something like this in your layout:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:textColor="@drawable/selector"
        android:button="@null" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:textColor="@drawable/selector"
        android:button="@null" />
</RadioGroup>
```

the selector.xml (added in the drawable folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" />
</selector>
```

This switches the text colors automatically. If you click a text, the textcolor switches to green and the other texts switch to black.

[image]